# How would I make an Use Case Diagram without user interaction?

Tags: cron, uml, webhooks, diagram, use-case-diagram

I've got the following problem:

Imagine I'm making a dashboard without any user input. The only time the values on the dashboard change is when webhooks in some tool get triggered or when a recurring cronjob calls a specific API endpoint to refresh data.

The user in this case only logs in and navigates to a specific page. How would I make a Use Case Diagram in this case? The user does nothing but watch, and things only change when a job is automatically ran, or externally (like a web hook).

Any ideas how I can tackle this?

What I've tried is basically making the Job Scheduler an actor, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do things.

Comment: I guess partly? All those examples still seem to have an active actor which triggers something.  I have several webhooks that trigger my system to do something, so not just a Scheduler. Could I just add those as passive actors (right side of the system in the diagram) with a line to a use case?

Comment: If you have no actor then you have no use case (and probably no system at all). Identify your actor and what the added value is it gets from the system under consideration.